# e.preventDefault(); Not working (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

How do I stop a form submit from actually submitting the page?

I tried `e.stopPropagation();` and `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();` but it didn't prevent the form from submitting the page

```
import React,{useState,useRef} from 'react';
import Counter from './components/Counter';
import Сlasscounter from './components/Classcounter';
import './styles/APP.css';
import Postlist from './components/Postlist';
 import Postitem from "./components/Postitem";
 import Mybutton from "./components/UI/button/Mybutton";
 import Myinput from "./components/UI/input/Myinput";
function App() {
 const [post,setpost]=useState([
  {id:1,title:'kickstart',body:'beginner'},
  {id:2,title:'backend',body:'back'},
  {id:3,title:'frontend',body:'description'},
  {id:4,title:'fullstack',body:'description'},
  {id:5,title:'architets',body:'description'},
  {id:6,title:'coding',body:'description'}
 ])
 const [title,setTitle]=useState('');
 const [body,setBody]=useState('');
 const addNewPost=function(e){
  /* e.stopPropagation();
  e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation(); */
  e.preventDefault();
   const newpost={
     title,
     body
   };
 console.log(newpost);
 };
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <form>
         <Myinput     
          value={title}
          onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
           placeholder="Description"/>
         <Myinput 
          type="text"
          placeholder="Description"
          value={body}
          onChange={e => setBody(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
           placeholder="Description"/>
          <Mybutton onclick={addNewPost}>Створити пост</Mybutton>       
       </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

[Problem is that after i click on button everything refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhVqn.png)

Comment: Right now your event is the button click event, not the form submit event.. so the solution would be to move the handler to the form. `<form onSubmit={addNewPost}>` and define the button as a submit type so it will trigger the form submission on click `<button type="submit">`

Comment: What does the `Mybutton` component look like? I'd say the problem is in there

Comment: <form onSubmit={addNewPost}> I Try this but it didn't work                         
<Mybutton> <form onSubmit={addNewPost}> Make post</form></Mybutton>  don't know why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Try

```html
<form onSubmit={addNewPost}>
```